# StringByAppendingString function does not work?

Tags: objective-c

```
 NSMutableString *chars=[ [NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""]   ;
    NSString *temp=[[self convertDecimalToChar:(digitizer%10)] copy]; //temp is good
    [chars stringByAppendingString:temp]; //chars is empty
```

Any idea whats wrong here ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`stringByAppendingString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString%3a) method is on the non-mutable [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) class, where non-mutable means *you cannot modify it*.

Therefore, as with most other `NSString` methods, it returns a new `NSString` object, in this case containing the original string plus whatever you passed in the parameter.

However given you are actually manipulating an [`NSMutableString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object, which *is* mutable, you probably want the [`appendString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/appendString%3a) method instead:

```
[chars appendString:temp];
```

Comment: i dont get it, if nsstring is non mutable ,so how can you add more strings to that ? from your answer i get that i have to change it to nsstring ?

Comment: @Curnelious Ah, I thought I covered that by saying that it returns a new object (not the original).

Comment: @Curnelious I have updated my answer with the use of `[NSMutableString appendString:]` which I believe is what you intended in the first place.

Comment: btw, can i swipe it ? so that abc becomes cba ?

Comment: @Curnelious Sorry I don't know what you mean.  You can also dump the use of `copy` in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
[chars stringByAppendingString:temp];
```

Is supossed to return a string combining both strings.

```
- (NSString *)stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)aString
```

If you want to just append a string to your string, do this:

```
[chars appendString:temp];
```

Find the documentation here:

[NSmutableString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString%3a) of this method, you need to do:

```
chars = [chars stringByAppendingString:temp];
```

It is returning a new NSString combining the two NSString, not actually changing the receiver.